# How should I test my mobile app's user interaction qualitatively?

Tags: android, ios, usability-testing, mobile-application, usability-study

How do you conduct qualitative research on mobile apps?

Do you use screen capturing tools, metrics, etc?

What metric did you find most indicative?

Comment: Performing such research is not a catch-all answer, nor are the metrics that are important. Each project should be evaluated independently for the best approach and for the metrics that are important -- for example, response time may be most important in one instance, while retention is more important in another. How you would go about testing in either of those situations would differ. As written, there is really no way we can answer the question without totally guessing.

Comment: @john-reiter Have you considered user testing and perhaps a site like usertesting.com - we've used them in the past, and they are an okay measure when trying to get user feedback. Not as good as running your own tests, but depending on your situation, they might work well.

Answer (score 3):

If I take your question title literally, then you're really after *qualitative* feedback rather than *quantitative* feedback. And, if that is the case, then the body of your question is only partly relevant.

In summary, **quantitative data** is a way of measuring something (be it a problem, issue, design, user interface, etc) by way of generating numerical data into useable statistics. In this way you can quantify attitudes, opinions, behaviours, and other defined variables from a sample population. Quantitative research is great for using measurable data to formulate facts and uncover patterns. It also helps to develop ideas or theories for potential follow-up qualitative research. Some examples of quantitative data would include the number of users who downloaded an app, the number that actually proceeded to checkout, the percentage of users who rated your app 5 stars, 4 stars, etc, the percentage of users who like your logo, the percentage of users who used your app daily, weekly, etc and so on. Typically quantitative data is collected via surveys, face-to-face interviews, polls, automated observations, server-side statistics, etc.

**Qualitative data** is information about qualities. Qualitative research is primarily exploratory research because it is used to gain an understanding of underlying reasons, opinions, motivations etc. For example, this type of research could provide insights into why a particular user interface isn't working as intended. Qualitative Research is often used to uncover trends in thought and opinions, or to delve deeper into a problem. It also helps to develop ideas or theories for potential follow-up quantitative research. Some common methods include focus groups (i.e. group discussions), individual interviews, and participation/observation. The sample size is typically small, and respondents are selected to fulfill a given quota.

So, qualitative information can't *easily* be measured numerically via surveys, polls, etc. Below are example survey questions to help illustrate the point:

**Sample *quantitative* survey question**

How easy do you find the user interface of our XYZ app to use?

- Very difficult
- Difficult
- Neutral
- Easy
- Very Easy

**Sample *qualitative* survey question**

In your own words, can you explain ***why*** you found the user interface of our XYZ app difficult to use?

As you can see, the quantitative question is **easy to collate** the figures for - i.e. how many users selected each of the options. This data can be represented numerically using both raw figures and percentages.

However, the qualitative question is **not easy to measure**. All the responses would have to be individually read to try and identify common themes, etc before it could be represented in any sort of quantitative way.

So, in terms of your particular question and app, it really gets down to what you're trying to measure. Your question title refers to the app's user interaction. If you already have a user base, you could actually start with a quantitative survey or poll and then, depending on those results, follow it up with a qualitative approach.

For example, if you have a user base of 1,000 people and were able to get survey responses back from 50 (which by the way would be a good result), and you discovered that 39 users (78%) found the app hard to use, you could then follow this up with qualitative research by seeking further feedback from those users to explore ***why*** they found it difficult to use.

If your app has no user base (e.g. it is yet to be launched) then you could organise a couple of focus groups of roughly the same size (e.g. 12 each) and provide them a device with the app installed and have them use it. You would then observe their participation and seek feedback, and try to generate a group discussion to capture the mood etc. This is easier if there is two of you, one to ask questions, lead the discussion, etc and one to take notes.

If focus groups aren't possible, you could instead achieve a similar thing one-on-one. This wouldn't create the circumstances for a group discussion and what thoughts/feedback that may provide, but you'd get individual usability feedback which is useful - just be careful not to be defensive if it isn't positive and try to get enough individual users to ensure some validity to the results.

Hopefully this helps you with what you're trying to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Start with business goals: What are you trying to achieve? Translate those to research goals: What do you need to find out to achieve those business goals? Translate that to a test plan: What methods will provide this information? 
That will dictate what research you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll give you more practical answer:

First, you **recruit 5 users with mobile phones**. You should use their phones for the tests.

Second, you should **instruct them** using [this script](http://www.indiana.edu/~audioweb/T284/krug_questions.html) (or similar).

Third, give the users to do the most important task on your app. If you sell bananas tell them to buy one.

Then, the part you are interested comes in. You should **watch the users where they encounter problems**. Each time the user has difficulty finding something or the user is confused, you write that down. Don't worry there would be plenty. The important thing is to **see where the users struggle** and after the test ask them why. After the test you can follow up with questions like, "how likely you are going to use this app in the real world", "Can you rate this app from 1 to 10" and so on. This way you get a lot of qualitative or subjective data.

Fourth, after you do 5 user test **gather all the data and synthesize it** into one file. You should have notes like, 3/5 users couldn't find this information, 2/5 wanted this, 4/5 liked this feature and so on.

Then you prioritize the problems and then fix them.

Fifth, repeat that process.